# With scrapy, how can get part of xpath parsed result?

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my part of spider:

```
def parse(self, response):

        titles = HtmlXPathSelector(response).select('//li')
        for title in titles:
            item = EksidefeItem()
            item['favori'] = title.select("//*[@id='entry-list']/li/@data-favorite-count").extract()
            item['entry'] = ['<a href=https://eksisozluk.com%s'%a for a in title.select("//*[@class='entry-date permalink']/@href").extract()]
            item['yazari'] = title.select("//*[@id='entry-list']/li/@data-author").extract()
            item['basligi'] = title.select("//*[@id='topic']/h1/@data-title").extract()
            item['tarih'] = title.select("//*[@id='entry-list']/li/footer/div[2]/a[1]/text()").extract()

            return item
```

I am getting date and time from `item['tarih']` but its not exact date and time it also has another values inside it. Here is an example of parsed data from it:

> 26.01.2017 20:04 ~ 20:07

I want to use only date part (10 characters from left) as

> 26.01.2017

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use string slicing to get just the date:

```
item['tarih'] = title.select("//*[@id='entry-list']/li/footer/div[2]/a[1]/text()").extract()
item['tarih'][0] = item['tarih'][0][:10]
```

But I would also add some validation (take a look at `datetime.datetime.strptime()`) to make sure you got a valid date.

Comment: @JoshKorsik What's the value of `item['tarih']`?

Comment: same "26.01.2017 20:04 ~ 20:07"

Comment: @JoshKorsik I realised that it's a list, try the new code above.

Comment: thanks its done now. Also have another question. how can I compare this result with todays date? I mean I want to parse data if this result equals todays date.

Comment: @JoshKorsik Glad it works. You can use `datetime.datetime.now()` to get the current date then compare it to the date you got, but the way this site works, is you should ask your 2nd question in a separate post. Then I would be happy to answer in detail. If my answer solved your problem, then I would appreciate if you mark my answer as the solution and upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [item loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#module-scrapy.loader). You can extend the [ItemLoader](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.loader.ItemLoader) class and write your own custom item loader like this.

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose

def tarih_modifier(value):
    return value[:10]

class MyCustomLoader(ItemLoader):
    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()
    tarih_in = MapCompose(tarih_modifier)
```

You can also write this class in a separate module. Now in the parse method you can use this loader class.

```
def parse(self, response):
    l = MyCustomLoader(item=EksidefeItem(), response=response)
    l.add_xpath('name', "//*[@id='entry-list']/li/footer/div[2]/a[1]/text()")
    # add the rest 
    return l.load_item()
```

Using loader class will give you much more convenience over customizing values.